# ImageButton in GridView header under UpdatePanel not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a form with update panel and containt a gridview. When users click on the ImageButton, there will be a div that showing 'Processing' and the footer will be showed with empty textboxes for data entry and saving purposes. I found out that the Save button works fine, but not the ImageButton in the header. When I clicked on the ImageButton, it won't fire unless I removed the UpdatePanel. Any suggestion?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" >
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <HeaderTemplate><center>
                         <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgAdd" AlternateText="Add" runat="server"
                           ImageUrl="~/img/tDocumentAdd.png" Width="15" Height="15"
                           OnClick="ImgAdd_Click" CausesValidation="false" /></center>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                   </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <asp:Button runat="Server" id="bthSave" OnClick="SaveData" />
         </ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be because the image button resides inside the header part of your grid view. Try putting a prerender event and registering the imagebutton as postback control

.aspx

```
<HeaderTemplate><center>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgAdd" AlternateText="Add" runat="server"
    ImageUrl="~/img/tDocumentAdd.png" Width="15" Height="15"
    OnClick="ImgAdd_Click" onprerender="ImgAdd_PreRender" /></center>
```

Code behind

```
protected void ImgAdd_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ImageButton btn=sender as ImageButton;
   ScriptManager sc = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
   sc.RegisterPostBackControl(btn);
}
```

Comment: hi Nisha, I put in your code and now the imagebutton onclick event can be fired. thanks a lot.
but it seem that the div that shows on top of the page is not working.... any idea?

Comment: Is that div inside updatePanel? Could you please show the aspx code?

Comment: Please note that the `ImgAdd` button will be working with full postback ie the whole page will be posted back irrespective of the update panel. If this answer helped you, please use the tick to mark as answer.

Comment: I have tried it but works fine. Is the div server control? Does it use `runat="server"`

Comment: Do you have anything like an alert message when that button is clicked? Even if the div is server control, i didn't see any difference

Comment: Hi Nisha. When i click on the button, the div is showing 'Processing, please wait' message, so I'm sure that the button was indeed clicked. I tried to remove the prerender code in the button, now the div is showing but the onclick event won't fire.

Comment: If you could send me the whole code, I could try and help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this code !!!.aspx!!!
 <HeaderTemplate><center>
     <asp:ImageButton ID="ImgAdd" AlternateText="Add" runat="server"
     ImageUrl="~/img/tDocumentAdd.png" Width="15" Height="15"
     OnClick="ImgAdd_Click" onprerender="ImgAdd_PreRender" /></center>
  code behind`enter code here !!!  (.cs)`   !!!
 protected void ImgAdd_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    ImageButton btn=sender as ImageButton;
   ScriptManager sc = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
   sc.RegisterPostBackControl(btn);
  }`
```